# play 2.0 how to define a finder with multiple keys

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

Assume that there is a Model bean with a unique contraint combining two columns (as composite primary keys) like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "key1", "key2" }) })
public class Rating extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="key1", nullable=false)
    public Post key1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="key2", nullable=false)
    public User key2;
    ...
}
```

How can i find a finder for the method with the following signature:

```
public static Rating get(Post key1, User key2) { ... }
```

Comment: AFAIK, you're not defining a composite key, but just an unique constraint between two properties. To define a composite key, you have to use the `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass` annotations.

Comment: `Post` and `User` are also Model classes in this example. So, would you recommend to define an `@IdClass` with `Post.key` and `User.key`?

Comment: I'd try with `@EmbeddedId`, see this article for an example (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2006/11/using_composite.html), but I did not test it with Ebean, it would be great if you could give some feedback ;-)

Comment: I'll give it a try over the weekend and update here. Thanks so far.

Comment: I've solved it using `@EmbeddedId` and a custom finder with `finder.where().eq("key1", key1.getKey()).eq("key2", key2.getKey()).findUnique();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you're not defining a composite key, but just an unique constraint between two properties. To define a composite key, you have to use the `@EmbeddedId`[[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html)] or `@IdClass`[[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html)] annotations.

I'll go with `@EmbeddedId`, you can see an example of use here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2006/11/using_composite.html